# ARRAYFORMULA SUM

Tags: google-sheets

I have a series of numbers in column A.

I want to get the digit sums in column B in a **single ArrayFormula** (if possible).

```
1) REGEXEXTRACT(A1&"",REPT("(.)",LEN(A1))))
// returns a horizontal text array eg: 123 => 1|2|3

2) ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1&"",REPT("(.)",LEN(A1)))))
// returns the horizontal text array as a number array

3) SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1&"",REPT("(.)",LEN(A1))))))
// returns the digit sum of value in column A
```

1. I cannot apply SUM() straight away to formula (1) as the returned array is text
2. Using (3) or otherwise, is it possible to use a single ArrayFormula to get the Digit Sum of values in column A

Thank you.

EDIT: sample [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cjLrds-TpDV0T-Qt9mvdU3uSkxf9bDDufPzfIZ12v70/edit#gid=1226378881) - currently, the formula is copied manually in column B - looking for a single ArrayFormula to do this.

Comment: You need to at least attempt this yourself before we can assist you.

Comment: I have, various combinations of the formula's posted. the posted formula's take me part way. So I can assume that such a single formula is possible ?

Comment: You should include some raw example data, as there may be a better way to begin the process.

Comment: updated OP with link to sample spreadsheet. No, the number o digits in column A is NOT the same.

Comment: @RiyazMansoor Please note that we are not a forum, we are a Q&A site. It's helpful that you provided all information required to answer your question eventually, but please remember to do so initially next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the maximum number of digits per cell =7,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(A1:A2,REPT("0",7)),"\B",""),""),ROW(A1:A7)^0))
```

- Change ALL instances of `7` to  the maximum number of digits per cell
- TEXT to make constant the number of digits
- REGEX to replace all `\B` with a arbitrary char
- SPLIT the char to give a matrix
- MMULT to multiply with a vertical `1` matrix to give  the desired result.